# Jumping between hi-lock matches

Tags: regex, emacs

Say I have `global-hi-lock-mode` enabled and at the top of an html page I have the following hi-lock directive, resulting from previous `M-s h w` command

```
<!-- Hi-lock: (("{{[[:alnum:].]+}}" (0 (quote hi-green) prepend)))
     Hi-lock: (("ng-\\w+" (0 (quote hi-blue) prepend)))
   -->
<div>
  <div> ng-model="Cntrl"</div>
  {{Cntrl.thing}}
</div>
```

So, when I visit the file in a buffer I have two regexps being highlighted blue and green (the `ng-model` and the `{{Cntrl.thing}}` in the example.  Is there a way to jump easily between the highlighted matches?

Comment: How about?  `re-search-forward` and/or `re-search-backward` -- you already have the `regexp` . . .  Type:  `M-x describe-function RET re-search-forward RET` and `M-x describe-function RET re-search-backward RET` for more information on said functions.

Comment: to clarify, are you after something like hl-find-patterns, but specific to each pattern i.e. jump to next 'green' pattern or jump to next 'blue' pattern?

Comment: I had a quick look at hi-lock and think you may be barking up the wrong tee. Hi-lock mode is great for highlighting based on a pattern, but it isn't really designed for helping with navigation. While it would be possible to extend it to do what you want, I think that will be more work than it is worth. Instead, have a look at some of the other packages which are designed to make jumping to new cursor locations easier. Which is best for you will depend on how you configure things, but I would look at hydra, and ace-jump to start with. Downside is having to maintain your regexp in two places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this function do what you want? It jumps to the next occurrence of any currently highlighted pattern (or to the end of the buffer if there are no occurrences after point).

```lisp
(defun my/hl-forward ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char
   (apply
    #'min
    (mapcar
     (lambda (pattern)
       (save-excursion
         (re-search-forward (car pattern) nil 'noerror)
         (point)))
     hi-lock-file-patterns))))
```

The backward counterpart should be straightforward to adapt: just search backward (`re-search-backward`) and take the `max` instead of the `min` position.